# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, macos

My app keeps crashing on iOS but android part is working smoothly

Help!

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView bridge]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f957cf1f340'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011227d8ab __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bdb6ba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011228cab8 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000013a17ee0a -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 264
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112281d71 ___forwarding___ + 1431
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112284068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   TestApp                       0x000000010169c204 +[ReactNativeBlobUtil getRCTEventDispatcher] + 244
    7   TestApp                       0x000000010169c6c4 __27-[ReactNativeBlobUtil init]_block_invoke + 36
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011679cd18 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011679df5b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001167aed55 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1463
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001167ae790 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001121dcb1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001121d7436 __CFRunLoopRun + 2482
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001121d66a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011fd1128a GSEventRunModal + 139
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000013a144ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000013a1499ef UIApplicationMain + 123
18  TestApp                       0x0000000100f8d678 main + 104
    19  dyld                                0x000000010ba342bf start_sim + 10
    20  ???                                 0x0000000203536310 0x0 + 8645731088
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
```

I tried deleting derived data and doing pod update and podinstall aswell as Clean build folder

Comment: When does the error occur? Pressing a button? App launch?

Comment: Launching the app and it auto closes. The solution was to downgrade the library which is react-native-blob-util

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be caused because the library you use might support only the latest iOS versions or it might be an outdated library. So try to figure out the issue by running you application in various iOS versions. The application will run in certain iOS versions based on the issue. If the app crashes again, try to run after uninstalling that library from your project.
Now the application will run. Try other libraries if that library isn't supporting the iOS version you use.

I got the same issue with PayPalCheckout Library which supports iOS versions higher that iOS 15. When I ran it on iOS 12 device I got the same issue, but when I tried to run it on iOS 15.7 it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-blob-util has released v0.17.3 which addresses this issue - see [this github issue](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/issues/197) and [this commit](https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/commit/6290b21c3b5e60626a19bb6ea43f1579e15a8626) for details.

The commit that fixes the issue changes the way the iOS event dispatcher is assigned.